# Solving a damped wave equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, wave-equation

I am trying to solve the equation

$$ \frac{d^2u}{dt^2}-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(c_s^2u+\nu\frac{du}{dt}\right)=0 $$

with initial conditions

$$u(x, 0)=0$$

$$\frac{du}{dt}|_{t=0}=0$$

and boundary conditions

$$ {\frac{du}{dx}}|_{x=0,1}=a\sin{(\omega_d t)}-b\cos{(\omega_d t)}$$

My attempts so far are

```
ClearAll[u, x, t, a, b, c, w, n];

c = 1;
n = 1;
a = 1;
b = 1;
w = 1;

pde = D[u[t, x], t, t] - c*D[u[t, x], x, x] - n*D[u[t, x], x, x, t] == 0;
ics = {u[0,x]==0};
bcs = 
  {(D[u[t,x],x] /. x->0) == a*Sin[w*t]-b*Cos[w*t], 
   (D[u[t,x],x] /. x->1) == a*Sin[w*t]-b*Cos[w*t]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ics, bcs}, u, {x, 0, 1},{t, 0, 10}]
```

but I am receiving multiple error messages. Among them:

> NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in (u^(0,1))[t,0]==-Cos[t]+Sin[t] in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[(u^(0,1))[t,0]==-Cos[t]+Sin[t],x==0.] needs to be linear.
>
> NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in (u^(0,1))[t,0]==-Cos[t]+Sin[t] in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[(u^(0,1))[t,0]==-Cos[t]+Sin[t],x==0.] needs to be linear.
>
> NDSolveValue::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.

How can I solve it?

Comment: 1. According to your code, The $\rho$s in $\LaTeX$ formula seem to be typos, if so, please correct them, if not, please clarify what's the relationship between $u$ and $\rho$. 2. To find a particular solution, one more initial condition is needed.

Comment: @xzczd yes,they are typos. Sorry for that, I will correct them.

Comment: With the new added i.c. `NDSolve` solves the problem without difficulty, `ibcinc` warning is generated, but it doesn't seem to be a big deal in this case.

Comment: @xzczd can you provide an example of your working code? Which warning do you get exactly?

Comment: `ClearAll[u, x, t, a, b, c, w, n];

c = 1;
n = 1;
a = 1;
b = 1;
w = 1;

pde = D[u[t, x], t, t] - c*D[u[t, x], x, x] - n*D[u[t, x], x, x, t] == 0;
ics = {u[0, x] == 0, D[u[t, x], t] == 0 /. t -> 0};
bcs = {(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == a*Sin[w*t] - b*Cos[w*t], (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) ==
     a*Sin[w*t] - b*Cos[w*t]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ics, bcs}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is necessary to divide the equation into two (second order), add the initial data and boundary conditions. Here is the code without adding boundary conditions

```
ClearAll[u, x, t, a, b, c, w, n];

c = 1;
n = 1;
a = 1;
b = 1;
w = 1;

pde = {D[u[t, x], t, t] - c*D[u[t, x], x, x] - n*D[v[t, x], t] == 0, 
   v[t, x] == D[u[t, x], x, x]};
ics = {u[0, x] == 0, v[0, x] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
bcs = {(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
    If[t <= 10^-6, 0, 
     a*Sin[w*t] - b*Cos[w*t]], (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == 
    If[t <= 10^-6, 0, a*Sin[w*t] - b*Cos[w*t]]};

{U, V} = NDSolveValue[{pde, ics, bcs}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
    "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 141, "MaxPoints" -> 141, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}]

DensityPlot[U[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can use boundary conditions twice, then there are no warnings

```
ClearAll[u, x, t, a, b, c, w, n];

c = 1;
n = 1;
a = 1;
b = 1;
w = 1;
f[t_] := If[t < 10^-6, 0, 1];
pde = {D[v[t, x], t] - c*D[u[t, x], x, x] - n*D[v[t, x], x, x] == 0, 
   v[t, x] == D[u[t, x], t]};
ics = {u[0, x] == 0, v[0, x] == 0};
bcs = {(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == (a*Sin[w*t] - b*Cos[w*t]) f[
      t], (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == a*Sin[w*t] - b*Cos[w*t] f[t]};
bcs1 = {(D[v[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
    w (a*Cos[w*t] + b*Sin[w*t]) f[t], (D[v[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == 
    w (a*Cos[w*t] + b*Sin[w*t]) f[t]};

{U, V} = NDSolveValue[{pde, ics, bcs, bcs1}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0,
     10}, Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
     "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
     "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 141, "MaxPoints" -> 141, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}];

{DensityPlot[U[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "u"], 
 DensityPlot[V[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "v"]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you for your answe, it is very useful. Though, I have a few doubts on your procedure: why did you add an IF condition in the boundary conditions? Is it needed to add the new initial condition v[0, x] == 0 ? Is there a particular reason why you specified all those options to solve the pde?

Comment: The initial conditions `Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0` and boundary conditions are not matched for `t = 0`. To harmonize these conditions, we excite the boundary conditions immediately at `t>0`.

Comment: If I try to run your code with mathematica 12, I receive the error `NDSolveValue::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.`. Furthermore, using discontinuous boundary conditions apparently causes the solution to have some artifacts at the time point of the discontinuity.

Comment: @AlessandroZunino You can remove `If[]`, but determine `Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x]`. Otherwise, we have a warning `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.`

Comment: If I remove the `if[]` indeed the error you quote appears, even if `Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x]==0` is present. Even if this happens, the solutions is still exactly the same you show. Some other errors appear: `NDSolveValue::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.`

Comment: @AlessandroZunino We can use boundary conditions twice, then there are no warnings - see update to my answer.